# Mostrar un confirm después de otro confirm con Alertify

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alertify

Estoy utilizando Alertify JS para mostrar cuadros de diálogo, el problema lo tengo cuando intento mostrar un mensaje de confirmación después de un mensaje de confirmación, el código que uso es el siguiente:

```
alertify.confirm("¿Está seguro que ya revisó que los datos de la recepción sean correctos?", function () { ValidaCampos(); })
```

y la función ValidaCampos:

```
function ValidaCampos() {
        if ($("#<%=rdbNO.ClientID%>").is(":checked") && $("#<%=txtDiferencia.ClientID%>").val().replace(",", "") >= 1000) {
            alertify.confirm("La diferencia es muy grande, ¿Está seguro que la recepción es en un solo tanque?", function () { alertify.success("OK") }, function () { alertify.error("CANCEL") });
        }
    }
```

Ese último confirm es el que no me lo muestra, pero cuando quiero mostrar un alertify.success o un alertify.alert si me los muestra.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta/respuesta te será de ayuda de SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871803/jquery-alertify-confirm-after-confirm-does-not-work

Comment: Muchas gracias ntzz, era exactamente lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto podría funcionar:

```
alertify.confirm("¿Está seguro que ya revisó que los datos de la recepción sean correctos?", function () { 


                 setTimeout(()=>{

             ValidaCampos(); 
             }, 1)
         }, 
    })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, precisamente eso era lo que necesitaba, solo bastaba con colocar el otro confirm dentro de un SetTimeOut